# Handle incoming Array from Guzzle

Tags: wordpress, laravel, httprequest, guzzle

So i have been trying to get guzzle working, i can send a post request which sends some kind of array and I would like to know, how can i receive it at an endpoint? i can handle things like if(isset($_POST['nameHere']))  but not the array thingy

```
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Test user',
            'password' => 'testpassword',
        ],

        'debug' => true
    ]);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r((string)$response->getBody(), true) . '</pre>';
}
```

ps: My custom laravel application is the sender, my wordpress site is the receiver.

Comment: What you get using `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, i was missing the .php ending in my url, because i chose not to test with httpbin but directly with my api.
and in wordpress i dont get anything because this is the sendercode i published not the receiver (wordpress). i wouldnt know how to test it. thanks anyway